# Different results of Math.hypot() on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, v8, hypotenuse

When I run the simple calculation below the results on Chrome and Firefox slightly differ.

Chrome: `56.1124478168614`

Firefox: `56.11244781686139`

```js
let x = -24.42;
let y = -50.519999999999925;
console.log(Math.hypot(x, y));
```

Is there a hole in the specification of `Math.hypot()` or is one of the browsers implementing it in a wrong way?

Edit: In Firefox `Math.hypot(x, y)` gives the same result as `Math.sqrt(x*x, y*y)`, in Chrome the result from `Math.hypot(x, y)` is slightly different. Therefore I suspect Firefox is doing the calculation correctly.

Comment: Not a dup, but [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Actually the results are same, only that Chrome seems to have limited the decimals to 13 digits.

Comment: @Teemu I know about floating point precision, but you sure would expect identical results from Javascript math on different browsers in 2020.

Comment: Why would you expect two different implementations of the same non-trivial computation to produce the same rounding errors? (Regardless of what year it is, or which language's implementation!)

Comment: The [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-math.hypot) says: "_Math.hypot returns an implementation-dependent approximation ..._".

Comment: @jmrk Because I would expect the rounding behaviour to be clearly specified (and it is with other parts of Javascript). But as Teemu pointed out, in this case the spec specifically mentions an implementation-dependent approximation, which explains the different behavior.

Comment: When looking at the rest of the Math functions in the standard, it looks like almost all the functions are implementation-dependent ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `Math.js` is the same code in both browsers, different engines have different algorithms for performing basic arithmetic. For example, there are many different methods of computing a square root, and it is unlikely that two different engines would share the exact same implementation.
There are efforts to standardise precision across engines, yet they are as of yet unsuccessful. See [this article](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/math-v8-broken-how-do-we-fix-it/) for example. 
As to why `Math.hypot` in Chrome would return a different value to doing the calculation manually in the same engine, `Math.hypot` is intended as an efficient approximation - not just a neat way of wrapping up the work into a single function. Thus, depending on the implementation, its results may differ from the actual calculation. You are right in stating that in this case, Firefox has the more numerically accurate implementation, as evidenced by your simple test.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the assumption that precision was already standardized for all parts of Javascript,.

Comment: Wow, that linked article is bad. Click-bait title with a bold claim, then gives no evidence in support of the claim. Also the answer to the headline's question is trivial: if V8 is broken (in Math or elsewhere), file a bug at crbug.com/v8/new. That said, differently rounded floating-point results do not constitute brokenness.

Comment: I agree that it is a clickbait title, but if you look up Athan Reines he is actually rather qualified, and his project is definitely an interesting example of what I discussed.

Comment: Sure, the interview itself is fine; it's only the way it's been turned into an article that I'm criticizing.

Answer (score 1):

> In Firefox `Math.hypot(x, y)` gives the same result as `Math.sqrt(x*x, y*y)`

That lets us make a fairly confident guess for how Firefox implemented `Math.hypot` :-)

> in Chrome the result from `Math.hypot(x, y)` is slightly different

Here is Chrome's implementation:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/src/builtins/math.tq#389

As you can see from the comment in line 421, a Kahan summation is used to avoid/minimize rounding errors -- so apparently the intention was to be *more* accurate than a simple `sqrt(x*x + y*y)` implementation. (I've tried to verify whether that's actually the outcome in this case, but Wolfram Alpha just rounds to `56.1124`, and I don't know of another convenient infinite-precision floating-point evaluator out there, so I can't say for sure.)

> doing the calculation correctly

In the presence of limited precision and rounding errors, the "correct" way is hard to define. For example, there are situations where the (mathematically equivalent!) expressions `(a * b) / c` and `a * (b / c)` produce different results due to rounding, and what's more, where the values of a, b, c determine which way of computing the result gets closer to the (unlimited-precision) theoretical result, so each implementation could get "lucky" or "unlucky".

Comment: You can get almost arbitrary precision with Casio's Keisan high precision calculator at https://keisan.casio.com/calculator
The actual result is something like 56.112447816861388657114451996508313946336113356817432975754273642793555379412475351986222291941521992138354723...